# Add a Spinner/Progress bar into a text view?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a `spinner/progress bar` into the **left side** of a `TextView`.

```
 ________________
| O   MY TEXT    |
|________________|

O = spinner/progress bar
```

At first my thought was to add a `TextView` and add a `ProgressBar` on top of it. Is it possible to do this in a `TextView` itself? if not what's best way to do this?

```
   <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/latlongLocation"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
            android:background="@drawable/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#202020"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

         <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ProgressBar
               android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
               style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you hardcode margin and widget sizes in your layout ? You could use style/dimension resources for consistency across your app. The same can be said about text colors or drawables.

Comment: @2Dee I'm a newbie to Android SDK, care to help me correct my code?

Answer (score 5):

Use FrameLayout. With it you can place views like in card stack.

Little example:

```
<!-- Example of parent -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <ProgressBar
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textSize="32dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Test text"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Would look like this

[image]

Comment: Awesome but now both `TextView` and `ProgressBar` has gone top left corner.

Comment: you got to set up the right margins, wait up, i'll edit the answer

Comment: Is possible to align the `FrameLayout` to bottom?

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right picture? There's only some gray stuff in it

Comment: Yeah, grey area is for the Google map. White square in the bottom center is the one I'm talking about.

Comment: Well if you add this => **android:gravity="bottom"** to LinearLayout in my example XML it will place the FrameLayout to the bottom of the screen.